# Update hours in 24 hour datetime field in oracle database

Tags: oracle10g

I`m trying to update time in datetime field as

```
UPDATE table_name 
   SET col_name=to_DATE('04/02/2012 00:12:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
WHERE col_name1='rer';
```

After updating in db,The `output` is like this

`'04/02/2012 12:12:00'`

Extra `12` it's adding in Hour field,
how can I make this not to add extra `12` to hour field???

Comment: How do you display the output (What query do you use)?

Comment: marcin,Just a select statement I use,like,"select col_name from tab_name" follwed by where condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UPDATE statement is OK. It does not add any "extra 12" to your date column. The only problem you have is with displaying the values. The date column does not store its values in any specific format like 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS', it contains binary data. When you query your  table with such statement like

```
SELECT col_name FROM table_name
```

the date is displayed using your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which is probably 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS'. In this format your date is displayed as '04/02/2012 12:12:00'. If you run following statement in your session

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

and then your query

```
SELECT col_name FROM table_name
```

you will see the date in your desired format. Other way is to use TO_CHAR like

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(col_name, ''MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM table_name
```

Comment: Marcin,first of all thanks for the reply,I still have same date format even after running your alter statement,I tried for this->SELECT TO_DATE('03/24/2012 00:30:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL..It still displays hours as "12" only

Comment: What tool do you use to perform those queries (SQL*Plus? PL/SQL Developer? SQL Developer? other?)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, there might be an error in the string used to format the output, with the '24' missing from 'HH24'. Since you only have the format string for the input (and not the output) listed above, I can't say whether that's the case. Here's an example of what I mean.

**Query 1:**

```
select to_char(to_date('04/02/2012 00:12:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

**Result 1:**

```
04/02/2012 00:12:00
```

**Query 2:**

```
select to_char(to_date('04/02/2012 00:12:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
    'mm/dd/yyyy HH:mi:ss') from dual;
```

**Result 2:**

```
04/02/2012 12:12:00
```

To be clear, I think the solution to your issue may be to check the format in your select statement, and select your data like this:

```
SELECT to_char(col_name,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM table_name WHERE col_name1='rer';
```

Comment: :I don't think that this is not the case ,though it give you the correct answer but in my when i try to execute the update using `hh:mi:ss` and time `00:12:00` it give me `ORA-08149 hour must be between 1 and 12 `

Comment: I don't mean he is using a format string like `hh:mi:ss` in his update statement, I am guessing he may be using it in a select statement not shown above. In that case he would have the correct time stored in his table, but it would be formatted incorrectly when he uses the select and to_char to view it. I don't think you will get ORA-08149 on a statement like `select to_char(#dateTimeField#, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:mi:ss') from #tableName#`

Comment: :yes we'll not get the above error while `selecting` but as mentioned by him ,he need to update the statement with  time `00:12:00` ,so an update fails in that case and thrw the above error.In my case `HH24:MI:SS` is working for me and getting the desired result `04/02/2012 00:12:00`  .I think this must be related with NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter in `v$parameter` data dictionary.

Comment: He never mentioned getting an exception when executing the update. The problem is that his `output` looks wrong. I was just guessing that maybe he is formatting the output incorrectly. If he uses `hh24:mi:ss` on the `update` but `hh:mi:ss` on the `select` it can give the problem mentioned. But I agree it may be something else entirely.

Comment: :Thats what i an saying ,i am getting this exception while putting `hh:mi:ss`.May be you interpreted wrong of what i said .Anyways need to find out the solution for that .

Comment: Gaurav,i`m getting the error you specified only when I try to update like this->UPDATE IWISHMASTER 
   SET ED=to_DATE('04/02/2012 00:12:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS') 
WHERE WT='rer'
Nothing much i`ve changed I`ve remoived 24 from HH24 tat`s it.

Comment: When it`s "00:12:00" we won`t able be to use "HH:MI:SS" format

Comment: What query do you use to select the data for output?

Comment: Just a select statement,like,select col_name from tab_name follwed by where condition.